# google docs: service unavailable when fired off trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a script in a google doc to read records from our database. when I run it manually it works great!

I set it on a 2-hour trigger and every time it runs I get this error:

6/15/17 4:50 AM |   myFunction | Service unavailable: Docs (line 4, file "Code")    | time-based | 6/15/17 4:52 AM

line 4 of my code is:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
```

i have also tried

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT_ID');
```

Any idea why the service is unavailable through the trigger but available when run manually?

Comment: Get the document's ID and use that.  Since the document is not open it is not active?  `var doc = DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT_ID_GOES_HERE');` The ID is the long set of characters between two \ in the URL  Starting with 1bZP7 and ending with TUzU here:   `https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bZP7qeGlg0ZIszKhIj8Dv6Vejlq-aA3rtTUzU/edit`

Comment: .getActiveDocument works for SpreadsheetApp, i guess i figured it worked the same way for DocumentApp.

your suggestion makes sense. i'll give it a go.

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't seem to work. i still get the error.

Comment: Can edit your question and post sample code?  Remove a couple parts of the document ID if you have tried that.  Maybe a sample of the 2 methods you tried.  Put it in the question and not as a comment, please.